# Rails 4 different validations in one model

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have page with 2 tabs (forms), which used for edit one object.

E.g. its User's info. In first tab there is personal info, in next tab there is billing info.

Each form has own Submit button. How I can validate fields separately. If I understood it right, when I'll try submit form with 4 fields (of 10), it will raise errors, that other fields (6 of 10) wrong.

What is right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 classes to reflect your UI:

```
class User
  has_one :user_info
  has_one :billing_info
end

class UserInfo
  belongs_to :user

  # add your validation
end

class BillingInto
  belongs_to :user

  # add your validation
end
```

In your controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user_info = @user.build_user_info
  @billing_info = @user.build_billing_info
end
```

Then in your views:

```
= form_for @user_info do |f|
= form_for @billing_info do |f|
```

You'll need 2 controllers to handle the `POST` requests. Should be named `UserInfosController` and `UserBillingInfosController` respectively.